# British Physics Olympiad Round 1 2010 Q2a - Find potential difference between A and B

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I've been trying some [British Physics Olympiad past papers](https://www.bpho.org.uk/past-papers/round-1). In the 2010 Section 2 paper, the first question is the following:

[image: BPhO 2010 Q2a]

I've never seen a circuit like this, and I'm unsure what the correct logic is. Unfortunately, the answer to this question does not seem to be in the mark scheme on the BPhO website.

My current thinking is that no current will flow through FA and BC, so the potential difference between AB is the same as that between FC. Also, the 12V and 8V cell seem to be opposing each other, so would they cancel out to make 4V? This logic gives me the answer of $\frac{4(5+0.5)}{10+5+0.5+0.5}=1.375V$

Could anyone tell me how to solve this problem, and if the logic above is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so the potential difference between AB is the same as that between FC

We can ignore the 4V to start with, but it'll be included later on...

The current in the main loop is 4/16 = 0.25A,  then try assigning numbers 'potentials' to each side of a battery or resistor.  Start with the 12V cell, putting 12V on the left and 0V on the right, then it's still 12V above the 10 Ohm resistor, but 9.5V below it (V=IR),  etc...you should come back to 0V when you've been around the circuit.

The numbers are 9.5V and 0.125V at F and C, so a potential difference of 9.375V, if we continue the potential numbers to A and B, there is no change from F to A but we must add 4V going from C to B (zero current so the 0.5 Ohm resistor near C doesn't matter), so the potentials at A and B are 9.5V and 4.125V with a potential difference between them of 5.375V.

Comment: @ Keeran Parthipan  and if the assumption is wrong you may need to subtract the 4V and so get 5.375V, still deciding this...

Answer (score 1):

Your logic its wrong because B and C do not have the same potential. No current flow from B to C so the potential fall in the resistance is zero. But the 4V cell is still there, so $\Delta V_{AF} = 0$ but $\Delta V_{BC} = 4V$ so $\Delta V_{AB} = \Delta V_{FC}\pm4V$. You must check if the sign is + or - I am not sure right now and it maybe depends of the current direction. Also be careful adding the 12V and the 8V cell, the best way of solve this problem is using the mesh law.